# como escrever um nome usando ponteiros

Tags: c, string, alocação, heap

Preciso de um programa que utilize memoria heap para armazenar um nome qualquer. de entrada temos o numero de caracteres do nome e, em seguida, o nome, por exemplo:

32

Josefina Penacho Reis dos Santos

A saída deve ser o nome, neste caso:

Josefina Penacho Reis dos Santos

Meu programa é o seguinte:

```
int main(void)
{

    char *vetor=NULL;                       //vetor é o nome da pessoa
    int tam;                                //tam é o numero de caracteres do nome (tamanho do espaço alocado)
    char *aux;                              //vetor auxiliar

    scanf("%d\n", &tam);                    //determinar o tamanho do espaço alocado

    vetor=(char*) malloc(tam*sizeof(char)); //alocar o espaço necessario
    vetor[tam]='\0';                        //final da string

    aux = vetor;

    for(;*aux != '\0';aux++)
    {
        printf("%c",*aux);                  //printar o nome 
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Não faço ideia de onde está o erro, me ajudem pf!! Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

1. É confuso, mas ao contrário do `printf`, no `scanf` você **não** deve tentar consumir o `\n` da entrada. `scanf` é uma função cheia de sutilezas, mas uma boa regra se você não quiser pensar muito é sempre escrever `" %d"`, `" %s"`, etc. na especificação de formato, com um espaço logo antes do `%`, e nenhum no final da string.
2. Você só tem um `scanf` no seu código; você está lendo o comprimento da string mas não a string em si.
3. O `'\0'` ocupa espaço; se você vai ler um nome de quatro caracteres, você precisa de **cinco** bytes (e portanto você precisa ajeitar a linha com o `malloc`):

   ```
   +---+---+---+---+----+
   | j | o | s | e | \0 |
   +---+---+---+---+----+
   ```
4. Pra ler linhas com espaços no meio, você deve usar `scanf(" %[^\n]", &var)`; o `" %s"` lê uma palavra de cada vez (e mesmo a versão com os colchetes falha se a linha puder **começar** com um espaço em branco — nesse caso, a única alternativa é fazer `fgets` pra dentro de um buffer e `fscanf` em cima desse buffer, o que é bem mais complicado).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Uma parte está resolvida, o problema agora é que, mesmo havendo um sobrenome, o programa só imprime o primeiro nome :/

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta pra tratar esse caso — você pode atualizar a pergunta pra mencionar que é possível que o nome tenha espaços no meio?

Comment: OK. O lance com o scanf(" %[^\n}", &var) resolveu o problema. Obrigado!

Comment: Em vez do `scanf()` sugiro o `fgets()` para ler linhas.