# Consultar vetor de uma tabela para atualizar outra em C

Tags: c, string, arquivo, ponteiro, funções

Olá. Sou novato aqui e nem sei se fui bem objetivo no título. Mas vamos lá.
Estou quase terminando meu projeto final de Algoritmos em C, e não estou conseguindo fazer a atualização de um item de uma tabela com a informação de outro.

Mais específico:

É um programa para agendar consultas médicas. Tenho a tabela de pacientes, médicos e consultas. As tabelas de pacientes e médicos estão funcionando 100% (gravação e alteração). Meu problema é na tabela de consultas. Inicio o módulo de gravar consultas. O consulta.id é gerado automático automático. Para escolher o consulta.paciente, invoco a listBoxPacientes para o usuário selecionar um dos pacientes e seu nome ser gravado em consulta.paciente, passo o endereço de memória para o ponteiro saida, depois ele recebe o novo conteúdo, quando volto para o módulo de gravação das consultas, o consulta.paciente não está com o nome escolhido.

Segue o código:

```
typedef struct paciente{
    int cod;
    char nome[30];
    char sexo[1];
    char endereco[50];
} Paciente;

typedef struct consulta{
    int id;
    char situacao[2];
    char medico[20];
    char paciente[30];  
    char data[11];
    char hora[6];
} Consulta;


void gravarConsulta(){
    Consulta consulta;
   ...
    listBoxPaciente(consulta.paciente, 3); // carrega listagem de pacientes             
    gotoxy(12,13); printf("%s", consulta.paciente); // entra com o nome do paciente
   ...
}

void listBoxPaciente(char *saida, int carregar){
   Paciente novoPaciente[50];
   ...
   if (carregar == 3)   {
      saida = novoPaciente[y].nome;
   }
   ...
}
```

Tudo o que preciso para terminar é escolher um dos pacientes da tabela pacientes.txt e gravar na tabela consultas.txt.
Ele está gravado o último consulta.nome que leu na hora de procurar o próximo consulta.id.

Espero que alguém consiga ajudar.

Comment: A função gravarConsulta é muito extensa? Você se incomodaria de postá-la na íntegra?

Comment: Como faço para postar. Aqui só deixa usar uns 500 caracteres.

Comment: Postei no google drive:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fBYLCTGQkbdGJBcVlOMVVneTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Talvez você não esteja conseguindo postar links por você ser um usuário novo. De qualquer forma, eu acho que eu não preciso mais ver o resto do código (vide resposta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que você queria dizer

```
void listBoxPaciente(char *saida, int carregar){
   Paciente novoPaciente[50];
   ...
   if (carregar == 3)   {
      strcpy(saida, novoPaciente[y].nome);
   }
   ...
}
```

pois do jeito que está o seu código `saida` é efetivamente uma variável local; alterá-la não vai afetar a `consulta` na outra função.

Comment: Olá. Agora funcionou, mas só está passando o nome, o sobrenome não está indo. Será que ele está considerando que o espaço é o caractere nulo?

Comment: Provavelmente o `novoPaciente[y].nome` está sendo populado incorretamente, mas é impossível responder sem saber como ele é preenchido. Você está lendo ele de um arquivo com `scanf(" %s", …)`? Se sim, vide [essa resposta aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67573/como-escrever-um-nome-usando-ponteiros/67574#67574). Se isso não resolver, e você não conseguir achar o erro, cabe fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: O arquivo de pacientes tem n registros. paciente.nome tem tamanho [30], mas o conteúdo é variável em tamanhos. Primeiro peço para ler todos os registros e guardar em um novo vetor, novoPaciente com [50] posições. Ele é exibido na tela numa caixa de listagem, o usuário usa o cursor para escolher um dos nomes. Ao apertar ENTER, a variável "saida" recebe o conteúdo de novoPaciente.

Comment: Esse strcpy deu o mesmo resultado. Só passou o nome. O sobrenome não foi.